# Having trouble selecting specific data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to only select specific data in a social network I am building. The session for the login is `$SESSION['user_login']` and it doesnt seem to be selecting the rows I need. Anyone got any ideas?

```
     <?php
    if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
         //check user exists
         $check = mysql_query("SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {
            $get       = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username  = $get['username'];
            $firstname = $get['first_name'];    
        }else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=index.php\">";  
            exit();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: mysql_query is kind of deprecated. If your a making a social network website I would suggest to use PDO or mysqli more safe..

Comment: Can you explain the problem? What are you expecting and what are you actually seeing? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

as said mention in the comment mysql_query is deprecated and woould suggest use of more safe extension. what do you meanby selecting **rows**. with your select query you will only get 1 row since you are accessing login information with unique username. Your code is right you get a row but there is not way to know whether it exist in your result. In order to debug you will have to echo it out. But you wont get any anything on your browser since you are using execute(that's what I call them) php tags which do not return result. You will need to use  instead of  to get your result echoed.

here is your fix-

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    //check user exists
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {
     $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
    $username = $get['username'];
    $firstname = $get['first_name'];    

    echo $username;
    echo $first_name;
   }
  else
  {
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=index.php\">";  
   exit();
   }
    }
    }
```

hope this helps..

Dins